# C - Moving or deleting multiple nodes based on value

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, linked-list

I am trying to make a program for Santa! My knowledge is limited; I am lost in pointers and loops etc, I've been thinking this for a couple hours.

I have an array of pointers to singly linked lists. Each array index indicates a list of children in age groups 0: 0-3, 1: 4-7, 2: 8-11, 3: 11 - 15.

Each child is a struct, now after each year I want to go through all the lists, increment their age by 1, and if they need to change an age group, I have to move the node to the appropriate list that holds that age group. If although the child gets over the age of 15 then it has to delete the node instead. My code is incomplete because I am new to linked lists and I got confused.

My main issue is that I make changes to the lists as I move through them, so if I check for the first node and I remove it, I have to check the first node again because now its a new one, so I  keep checking until the Head is okay, is this the right approach? I am not sure my code works, I cant test it yet.

the part from my Santa_Claus.h:

```
/*Structure defining a node of the children list*/
struct child {
    int cid; /*The identifier of the child.*/
    int age; /*The age of the child.*/
    int did; /*The identifier of the child.*/
    int present_choices[M]; /*The array in which the preferences of the child for presents are stored*/
    struct child *next; /* Singly-linked, sorted by id */
};
```

the part from Santa_Claus.c

```
#define N 4 /*Number of children's age categories*/
struct child *Age_categories[N];

int new_season(void) {
    int i;
    struct child *childP = NULL;
    struct child *prev = NULL;
    struct child *childptr = NULL;
    int MaxAges[N] = {3,7,11.15};

    //Increment Age Loop
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++){

    childP = Age_categories[i];
        while(childP != NULL){
            childP->age = childP->age + 1;
            childP = childP->next;
        }
    }

    //Remove or Move Loop
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
        childP = Age_categories[i];

        //while the first is still > than the max age of this category
        while(childP->age > MaxAges[i]){
                if(i != (N-1)){
                    childP->next = Age_categories[i+1];
                    Age_categories[i+1] = childP;
                }else{
                    Age_categories[i] = childP->next;
                }
                childP = childP->next;
        }



        prev = Age_categories[i];
        childP = prev->next;

        while(childP != Null){

            if(childP->age > MaxAges[i]){
                if(i != (N-1)){
                    prev->next = childP->next;
                    childP->next = Age_categories[i+1];
                    Age_categories[i+1] = childP;
                }else{
                    Age_categories[i] = childP->next;
                }

            }
            prev = childP;
            childP = childP->next;
        }

    }

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: What is the question/problem here?

Comment: Needs 'nice/naughty' boolean.

Comment: @AntoineMathys Thanks for your time taking a look at it.  I guess I would have to go back and sort the lists one by one afterwars I guess? even though it's not efficient. There are too many things going on while i move through the lists and am lost!

Comment: strongly suggest: 1) break the code into steps. 2) implement/test each step 3) call those step sequentially to achieve the desired result.   IMO: at the yearly update event.  1) for each list age each child in the list 2) for each list except top age group list: if child has exceeded the age group,a) extract child from current list b) save child into next/older age group list 3) for oldest age group list only, if child exceeds top age remove from list and discard child.   Suggest making each step a separate sub function.   be sure to handle special cases, like an empty list.

Comment: int MaxAges[N] = {3,7,11.15};   That's a decimal instead of a comma.

Answer (score 0):

> My main issue is that I make changes to the lists as I move through them, so if I check for the first node and I remove it, I have to check the first node again because now its a new one, so I keep checking until the Head is okay, is this the right approach?

In place edits will bite you at the edge-cases.  You'll have problems with the head and the tail nodes. If you remove the head, then whatever was keeping track of your head now points to nullspace.

In short, you just have to be careful. There are a lot of ways to screw it up. And for newbies, I'd suggest you stay away from pointers in C. Powerful, but a pain in the ass.   Stick to fixed arrays unless you really need this thing to scale.

You don't need to re-check the head so much as have a special case to check the head, and do head-safe edits.  Also checking if the set is empty, and checking the tail are typically good ideas.  You can try and figure out something clever to avoid that sort of thing and have smooth code that handles it all... But clever code often bites you in the ass just as much.

Comment: lt is an assignment i have so I guess i will figure it out eventually i hope, have a nice day , and thanks for taking the time for this, every bit of advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> My main issue is that I make changes to the lists as I move through
>   them, so if I check for the first node and I remove it, I have to
>   check the first node again because now its a new one, so I keep
>   checking until the Head is okay, is this the right approach?

In principle it's the right approach, but you have to do that not only for the head, but for every node in each list. Your code works not in all cases, e. g.

```
        //while the first is still > than the max age of this category
        while(childP->age > MaxAges[i]){
                if(i != (N-1)){
                    childP->next = Age_categories[i+1];
                    Age_categories[i+1] = childP;
                }else{
                    Age_categories[i] = childP->next;
                }
                childP = childP->next;
        }
```

constitutes an endless loop if let's say the head child in age group 0 has become 4 years old.

---

Consider this correct code, which is shorter and therefore gives less opportunity for mistakes:

```
    // Remove or Move Loop
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        struct child **chPA;    // address of pointer to node under check
        // for each node in age group i
        for (chPA = &Age_categories[i]; childP = *chPA; )
            if (childP->age > MaxAges[i])
            {
                *chPA = childP->next;   // remove node from this list
                if (i != N-1)
                {
                    struct child **chPA;    // address of pointer to node in next group
                    // find where in next group to insert the aged node
                    for (chPA = &Age_categories[i+1]; childptr = *chPA;
                         chPA = &childptr->next)
                        if (childptr->cid > childP->cid) break;
                    (*chPA = childP)->next = childptr;
                }
                else
                    free(childP);   // delete the grown out node
            }
            else
                chPA = &childP->next;   // proceed to next node
    }
```

(It inserts a node in the next higher age group according to its `cid` because of your code comment

```
    struct child *next; /* Singly-linked, sorted by id */
```